# Percentage difference per category in the same raw, Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on a report in Power BI, and I faced a problem. I want to do a simple thing (in DAX or in every way possible), that is: create a column in the report that is a percentage difference per category specified. The category that I want to consider is just one, and is specified in the same row named "Element to compare". To clarify the question I put here an example:

| Element | Total Value | Element to compare the total | total %diff from element specified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 334 | C | 178,3% |
| B | 323 | D | -73,8% |
| C | 120 | A | -64,1% |
| D | 1234 | A | 269,5% |

I want to create the column "%DIFF FORM ELEMENT SPECIFIED" but I can't find a simple way to do it, anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which Logic gives you the percentage difference ?

Comment: In the first row simply: (120-334)/120. The calculation it's easy, but I can't do it in Dax becouse I'm not practic with the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data to be the table you posted in your question without the % column

`T` table

[image: T table]

it's possible to write a measure to compute the current row total value, then the value for the element to compare, by setting a filter context over the element to compare with `CALCULATE` and at last compute the percentage using `DIVIDE`

```
%DIFF FORM ELEMENT SPECIFIED =
VAR CurrentValue =
    SUM ( T[Total Value] )
VAR ElementToCompare =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( T[Element to compare the total] )
VAR CompareValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( T[Total Value] ),
        T[Element] = ElementToCompare,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( T )
    )
VAR Result =
    DIVIDE (
        CurrentValue - CompareValue,
        CompareValue
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

using this measure in a table visual we get the desired table

[image: resulting table visual]

Answer (score 0):

Use `DAX` to get the value need for finding difference and then do the calcualtion. I'm splitting this into 2 for better understanding.

1. create a new column using `LOOKUPVALUE` to get the value to be compared.

   ```
   Value to be compared = LOOKUPVALUE([Total Value],[Element],[Elemet to be compared])
   ```

   [image]
2. Now it is simple.Use your calculation in the another column. *Make sure you are using `%` format for this column.*

   ```
   total %diff from element specified = ('Table'[Total Value] - 'Table'[Value to be compared])/'Table'[Value to be compared]
   ```

   [image]